# 5x Performance with Parallel.For... on a Dual Core?

Tags: c#, multithreading, optimization, task-parallel-library

I was doing some experimental calculations for fun, when I came across an interesting result:

```
Completed 1024x1024 pixels with 700 points in...
For Loop (Inline): 19636ms
For Loop: 12612ms
Parallel.For Loop: 3835ms
```

Which is not what I expected.

System:  Windows 7 64, i3 2120 [dual core, 4 threads], Visual Studio 2010.

Build : Optimization's on, Release mode [no debugger], 32 Bit.

Of secondary interest is the disappointing 64 bit performance.  While it's more inline of what I'd expect in terms of ratio's it accomplishes this by being slower across the board.

```
Completed 1024x1024 pixels with 700 points in...
For Loop (Inline): 23409ms
For Loop: 24373ms
Parallel.For Loop: 6839ms
```

The calculation is simple: For the indices x & y find the closest Vector3 and store it in 2D array.

The question, if you dare, is to try to explain why the inline for loop is so slow.  Bonus points for explaining the 64bit versions lack of performance.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TextureFromPoints
{
    class Program
    {
        const int numPoints = 700;
        const int textureSize = 1024;

        static Random rnd = new Random();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Starting");
                Console.WriteLine();

                var pointCloud = new Vector3[numPoints];

                for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
                    pointCloud[i] = new Vector3(textureSize);

                var result1 = new Vector3[textureSize, textureSize];
                var result2 = new Vector3[textureSize, textureSize];
                var result3 = new Vector3[textureSize, textureSize];

                var sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                for (int x = 0; x < textureSize; x++)
                    for (int y = 0; y < textureSize; y++)
                    {
                        var targetPos = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
                        var nearestV3 = pointCloud[0];
                        var nearestV3Distance = nearestV3.DistanceToPoint(targetPos);

                        for (int i = 1; i < numPoints; i++)
                        {
                            var currentV3 = pointCloud[i];
                            var currentV3Distance = currentV3.DistanceToPoint(targetPos);
                            if (currentV3Distance < nearestV3Distance)
                            {
                                nearestV3 = currentV3;
                                nearestV3Distance = currentV3Distance;
                            }
                        }
                        result1[x, y] = nearestV3;
                    }
                sw1.Stop();

                var sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                for (int x = 0; x < textureSize; x++)
                    for (int y = 0; y < textureSize; y++)
                        Computation(pointCloud, result2, x, y);
                sw2.Stop();


                var sw3 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                Parallel.For(0, textureSize, x =>
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < textureSize; y++)
                        Computation(pointCloud, result3, x, y);
                });
                sw3.Stop();

                Console.WriteLine("Completed {0}x{0} pixels with {1} points in...", textureSize, numPoints);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", "For Loop (Inline)", sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", "For Loop", sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", "Parallel.For Loop", sw3.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Verifying Data: ");
                Console.WriteLine(CheckResults(result1, result2) && CheckResults(result1, result3) ? "Valid" : "Error");
                Console.WriteLine(); Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        private static bool CheckResults(Vector3[,] lhs, Vector3[,] rhs)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < textureSize; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y < textureSize; y++)
                    if (!lhs[x, y].Equals(rhs[x, y]))
                        return false;
            return true;
        }

        private static void Computation(Vector3[] pointCloud, Vector3[,] result, int x, int y)
        {
            var targetPos = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
            var nearestV3 = pointCloud[0];
            var nearestV3Distance = nearestV3.DistanceToPoint(targetPos);

            for (int i = 1; i < numPoints; i++)
            {
                var currentV3 = pointCloud[i];
                var currentV3Distance = currentV3.DistanceToPoint(targetPos);
                if (currentV3Distance < nearestV3Distance)
                {
                    nearestV3 = currentV3;
                    nearestV3Distance = currentV3Distance;
                }
            }
            result[x, y] = nearestV3;
        }

        struct Vector3
        {
            public float x;
            public float y;
            public float z;

            public Vector3(float x, float y, float z)
            {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.z = z;
            }
            public Vector3(float randomDistance)
            {
                this.x = (float)rnd.NextDouble() * randomDistance;
                this.y = (float)rnd.NextDouble() * randomDistance;
                this.z = (float)rnd.NextDouble() * randomDistance;
            }

            public static Vector3 operator -(Vector3 a, Vector3 b)
            {
                return new Vector3(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y, a.z - b.z);
            }

            public float sqrMagnitude()
            {
                return x * x + y * y + z * z;
            }

            public float DistanceToPoint(Vector3 point)
            {
                return (this - point).sqrMagnitude();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:  Thanks to the efforts of **Drew Marsh** we now have this super optimized version that inlines all the V3 operations.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TextureFromPoints
{
    class RevisedProgram
    {
        const int numPoints = 700;
        const int textureSize = 1024;

        static Random rnd = new Random();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Starting REVISED");
                Console.WriteLine();

                var pointCloud = new Vector3[numPoints];

                for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
                    pointCloud[i] = new Vector3(textureSize);

                var result1 = new Vector3[textureSize, textureSize];
                var result2 = new Vector3[textureSize, textureSize];
                var result3 = new Vector3[textureSize, textureSize];

                var sw1 = Inline(pointCloud, result1);

                var sw2 = NotInline(pointCloud, result2);

                var sw3 = Parallelized(pointCloud, result3);

                Console.WriteLine("Completed {0}x{0} pixels with {1} points in...", textureSize, numPoints);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", "For Loop (Inline)", sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", "For Loop", sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", "Parallel.For Loop", sw3.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Verifying Data: ");
                Console.WriteLine(CheckResults(result1, result2) && CheckResults(result1, result3) ? "Valid" : "Error");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        private static Stopwatch Parallelized(Vector3[] pointCloud, Vector3[,] result3)
        {
            var sw3 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            Parallel.For(0, textureSize, x =>
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < textureSize; y++)
                    Computation(pointCloud, result3, x, y);
            });
            sw3.Stop();
            return sw3;
        }

        private static Stopwatch NotInline(Vector3[] pointCloud, Vector3[,] result2)
        {
            var sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int x = 0; x < textureSize; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y < textureSize; y++)
                    Computation(pointCloud, result2, x, y);
            sw2.Stop();
            return sw2;
        }

        private static Stopwatch Inline(Vector3[] pointCloud, Vector3[,] result1)
        {
            var sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int x = 0; x < textureSize; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y < textureSize; y++)
                {
                    var targetPos = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
                    var nearestV3 = pointCloud[0];
                    Vector3 temp1 = new Vector3(nearestV3.x - targetPos.x, nearestV3.y - targetPos.y, nearestV3.z - targetPos.z);
                    var nearestV3Distance = temp1.x * temp1.x + temp1.y * temp1.y + temp1.z * temp1.z;

                    for (int i = 1; i < numPoints; i++)
                    {
                        var currentV3 = pointCloud[i];
                        Vector3 temp2 = new Vector3(currentV3.x - targetPos.x, currentV3.y - targetPos.y, currentV3.z - targetPos.z);
                        var currentV3Distance = temp2.x * temp2.x + temp2.y * temp2.y + temp2.z * temp2.z;
                        if (currentV3Distance < nearestV3Distance)
                        {
                            nearestV3 = currentV3;
                            nearestV3Distance = currentV3Distance;
                        }
                    }
                    result1[x, y] = nearestV3;
                }
            sw1.Stop();
            return sw1;
        }

        private static bool CheckResults(Vector3[,] lhs, Vector3[,] rhs)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < textureSize; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y < textureSize; y++)
                    if (!lhs[x, y].Equals(rhs[x, y]))
                        return false;
            return true;
        }

        private static void Computation(Vector3[] pointCloud, Vector3[,] result, int x, int y)
        {
            var targetPos = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
            var nearestV3 = pointCloud[0];
            Vector3 temp1 = new Vector3(nearestV3.x - targetPos.x, nearestV3.y - targetPos.y, nearestV3.z - targetPos.z);

            var nearestV3Distance = temp1.x * temp1.x + temp1.y * temp1.y + temp1.z * temp1.z;

            for (int i = 1; i < numPoints; i++)
            {
                var currentV3 = pointCloud[i];
                Vector3 temp2 = new Vector3(currentV3.x - targetPos.x, currentV3.y - targetPos.y, currentV3.z - targetPos.z);
                var currentV3Distance = temp2.x * temp2.x + temp2.y * temp2.y + temp2.z * temp2.z;
                if (currentV3Distance < nearestV3Distance)
                {
                    nearestV3 = currentV3;
                    nearestV3Distance = currentV3Distance;
                }
            }
            result[x, y] = nearestV3;
        }


        struct Vector3
        {
            public float x;
            public float y;
            public float z;

            public Vector3(float x, float y, float z)
            {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.z = z;
            }
            public Vector3(float randomDistance)
            {
                this.x = (float)rnd.NextDouble() * randomDistance;
                this.y = (float)rnd.NextDouble() * randomDistance;
                this.z = (float)rnd.NextDouble() * randomDistance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it gives the following results:

x86

```
Completed 1024x1024 pixels with 700 points in...
For Loop (Inline): 3820ms
For Loop: 3962ms
Parallel.For Loop: 1681ms
```

x64

```
Completed 1024x1024 pixels with 700 points in...
For Loop (Inline): 10978ms
For Loop: 10924ms
Parallel.For Loop: 3073ms
```

So the good news is that we can drastically increase the performance of this code - and get the single threaded version to be operating at a speed somewhat in keeping with its parallel cousin.

The bad news is that this means ditching x64 entirely and manually in-lining all math.

At this stage, I'm very disappointed in the performance of the compilers - I expected them to be much better.

**Conclusion**

This is fubar and sad... and while we don't really know why we can make an educated guess to it being caused by a stupid compiler/s.  24s to 3.8s simply by changing the compiler from x64 to x86 and doing some manual in-lining is not what I'd expect.  However I've finished off the proof of concept I was writing, and thanks to a simple spacial hash I can compute a 1024 by 1024 image with 70,000 'points' in 0.7s - ~340000% faster than that of my original x64 scenario and with no threading or in-lining.  As such I've accepted an answer - the immediate need is gone, though I'l be still looking into the issue.

The code is available [here](http://pastebin.com/dACaZ8dE) and [here](http://pastebin.com/KWkfDmVT) - it generates a nice Voronoi diagram as a side effect :P

Comment: Your Dual Core is more like a 4-core, or at least 2+2.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, no it's kinda like a dual :P  in the latest tests once you get the stupid compiler out of the way the performance is only 226% that of a single core - which is more in line of what I'd expect of a dual core + ~20-40% boost thanks to Hyper-Threading.

Comment: Without stating the test etc a sigle number is kinda meaningless. I have seen benchmarks where a 2+2 gets to over 350%

Comment: @Henk Holterman - Not only do I state the test, I provide the code.  What's of interest to me is why what I'd normally assume of be the default fast efficient code is extremely slow and inefficient.  This is not trying to prove single thread is slow, but asking why it *IS* slow on code that's being developed for a real world application!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**All data from 8 core i7, Win7, x64**

It's surprising that you get 5x for sure. One problem with this test as you've written it is that you've put all three approaches in your Main method which is forcing gobblygook that the compiler has to create and keep synched to fulfill the needs of the closure used in the `Parallel.For` is getting in the way of the inline method. If you break out the work as follows you will see significantly faster performance in all three implementations... for x86 at least:

**Before x86:**

```
For Loop (Inline): 24313ms 
For Loop: 25236ms 
Parallel.For Loop: 3840ms
```

**After x86:**

```
For Loop (Inline): 13007ms
For Loop: 13013ms
Parallel.For Loop: 2208ms
```

So, looking at my x86 Parallel.For results, you see it scales at about ~5.9x and each version is much quicker when isolated.

Next, it's interesting to note that there's absolutely no gain in x64 after this same change. In fact, it ended just a little higher in each run on 2 of 3 tests consistently.

**Before x64**

```
For Loop (Inline): 24222ms
For Loop: 25197ms
Parallel.For Loop: 3810ms
```

**After x64**

```
For Loop (Inline): 25302ms
For Loop: 25209ms
Parallel.For Loop: 3821ms
```

I don't have a direct answer why why x64 would be so bad other than the fact that people consistently come up with code like this that makes the x64 JIT look bad, so maybe someone else can chime in on that.

That said I do have one other thing you might want to consider looking into in such an implementation: cache line invalidation. [There is an awesome MSDN article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc872851.aspx) written by @StephenToub that explains what this is all about. The TL;DR; of it is that, because all your data is stored in one array and diff. cores with different local (L2) caches are going to modify parts of that array they have to synchronize the data with the other cores with whom they overlap. If the sections the diff. cores are working on are too close together you're going to end up with a lot of these synchronizations which can eat into your parallel gains. The article shows a technique where you actually allocate extra space in your working array sufficient enough to separate the actual sections containing the data you're going to work on so that when those cores work on the data they don't have to invalidate the other cores. of the for loop rather than being closer to 8x than that. I would bet if you put in the work to address any cache line invalidation that you could squeeze another 10%+ out of it. Just remember there's always some overhead in setting up and coordinating the parallel work so you'll never get 100% perfection.

Here's the revised version of your program with each approach factored into separate methods:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TextureFromPoints
{
    class RevisedProgram
    {
        const int numPoints = 700;
        const int textureSize = 1024;

        static Random rnd = new Random();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Starting REVISED");
                Console.WriteLine();

                var pointCloud = new Vector3[numPoints];

                for(int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
                    pointCloud[i] = new Vector3(textureSize);

                var result1 = new Vector3[textureSize, textureSize];
                var result2 = new Vector3[textureSize, textureSize];
                var result3 = new Vector3[textureSize, textureSize];

                var sw1 = Inline(pointCloud, result1);

                var sw2 = NotInline(pointCloud, result2);


                var sw3 = Parallelized(pointCloud, result3);

                Console.WriteLine("Completed {0}x{0} pixels with {1} points in...", textureSize, numPoints);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", "For Loop (Inline)", sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", "For Loop", sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", "Parallel.For Loop", sw3.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Verifying Data: ");
                Console.WriteLine(CheckResults(result1, result2) && CheckResults(result1, result3) ? "Valid" : "Error");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        private static Stopwatch Parallelized(Vector3[] pointCloud, Vector3[,] result3)
        {
            var sw3 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            Parallel.For(0, textureSize, x =>
            {
                for(int y = 0; y < textureSize; y++)
                    Computation(pointCloud, result3, x, y);
            });
            sw3.Stop();
            return sw3;
        }

        private static Stopwatch NotInline(Vector3[] pointCloud, Vector3[,] result2)
        {
            var sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for(int x = 0; x < textureSize; x++)
                for(int y = 0; y < textureSize; y++)
                    Computation(pointCloud, result2, x, y);
            sw2.Stop();
            return sw2;
        }

        private static Stopwatch Inline(Vector3[] pointCloud, Vector3[,] result1)
        {
            var sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for(int x = 0; x < textureSize; x++)
                for(int y = 0; y < textureSize; y++)
                {
                    var targetPos = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
                    var nearestV3 = pointCloud[0];
                    var nearestV3Distance = nearestV3.DistanceToPoint(targetPos);

                    for(int i = 1; i < numPoints; i++)
                    {
                        var currentV3 = pointCloud[i];
                        var currentV3Distance = currentV3.DistanceToPoint(targetPos);
                        if(currentV3Distance < nearestV3Distance)
                        {
                            nearestV3 = currentV3;
                            nearestV3Distance = currentV3Distance;
                        }
                    }
                    result1[x, y] = nearestV3;
                }
            sw1.Stop();
            return sw1;
        }

        private static bool CheckResults(Vector3[,] lhs, Vector3[,] rhs)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < textureSize; x++)
                for(int y = 0; y < textureSize; y++)
                    if(!lhs[x, y].Equals(rhs[x, y]))
                        return false;
            return true;
        }

        private static void Computation(Vector3[] pointCloud, Vector3[,] result, int x, int y)
        {
            var targetPos = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
            var nearestV3 = pointCloud[0];
            var nearestV3Distance = nearestV3.DistanceToPoint(targetPos);

            for(int i = 1; i < numPoints; i++)
            {
                var currentV3 = pointCloud[i];
                var currentV3Distance = currentV3.DistanceToPoint(targetPos);
                if(currentV3Distance < nearestV3Distance)
                {
                    nearestV3 = currentV3;
                    nearestV3Distance = currentV3Distance;
                }
            }
            result[x, y] = nearestV3;
        }

        struct Vector3
        {
            public float x;
            public float y;
            public float z;

            public Vector3(float x, float y, float z)
            {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.z = z;
            }
            public Vector3(float randomDistance)
            {
                this.x = (float)rnd.NextDouble() * randomDistance;
                this.y = (float)rnd.NextDouble() * randomDistance;
                this.z = (float)rnd.NextDouble() * randomDistance;
            }

            public static Vector3 operator -(Vector3 a, Vector3 b)
            {
                return new Vector3(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y, a.z - b.z);
            }

            public float sqrMagnitude()
            {
                return x * x + y * y + z * z;
            }

            public float DistanceToPoint(Vector3 point)
            {
                return (this - point).sqrMagnitude();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Update:

Based on what Feng Yuan pointed out about the methods not being inlined by the x64 JIT, you can change the program to do the calculations inline instead and get better performance out of the x64 version than the x86 version. This obviously sucks, but this is the kind of thing that I've seen the x64 JIT destroy before. Here's the new numbers:

**After inlining x64:**

```
For Loop (Inline): 19032ms
For Loop: 19209ms
Parallel.For Loop: 3015ms
```

Inlined version of the code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TextureFromPoints
{
    class RevisedProgram
    {
        const int numPoints = 700;
        const int textureSize = 1024;

        static Random rnd = new Random();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Starting REVISED");
                Console.WriteLine();

                var pointCloud = new Vector3[numPoints];

                for(int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
                    pointCloud[i] = new Vector3(textureSize);

                var result1 = new Vector3[textureSize, textureSize];
                var result2 = new Vector3[textureSize, textureSize];
                var result3 = new Vector3[textureSize, textureSize];

                var sw1 = Inline(pointCloud, result1);

                var sw2 = NotInline(pointCloud, result2);


                var sw3 = Parallelized(pointCloud, result3);

                Console.WriteLine("Completed {0}x{0} pixels with {1} points in...", textureSize, numPoints);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", "For Loop (Inline)", sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", "For Loop", sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", "Parallel.For Loop", sw3.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Verifying Data: ");
                Console.WriteLine(CheckResults(result1, result2) && CheckResults(result1, result3) ? "Valid" : "Error");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        private static Stopwatch Parallelized(Vector3[] pointCloud, Vector3[,] result3)
        {
            var sw3 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            Parallel.For(0, textureSize, x =>
            {
                for(int y = 0; y < textureSize; y++)
                    Computation(pointCloud, result3, x, y);
            });
            sw3.Stop();
            return sw3;
        }

        private static Stopwatch NotInline(Vector3[] pointCloud, Vector3[,] result2)
        {
            var sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for(int x = 0; x < textureSize; x++)
                for(int y = 0; y < textureSize; y++)
                    Computation(pointCloud, result2, x, y);
            sw2.Stop();
            return sw2;
        }

        private static Stopwatch Inline(Vector3[] pointCloud, Vector3[,] result1)
        {
            var sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for(int x = 0; x < textureSize; x++)
                for(int y = 0; y < textureSize; y++)
                {
                    var targetPos = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
                    var nearestV3 = pointCloud[0];
                    Vector3 temp1 = nearestV3 - targetPos;
                    var nearestV3Distance = temp1.x * temp1.x + temp1.y * temp1.y + temp1.z * temp1.z;

                    for(int i = 1; i < numPoints; i++)
                    {
                        var currentV3 = pointCloud[i];
                        Vector3 temp2 = currentV3 - targetPos;
                        var currentV3Distance = temp2.x * temp2.x + temp2.y * temp2.y + temp2.z * temp2.z;
                        if(currentV3Distance < nearestV3Distance)
                        {
                            nearestV3 = currentV3;
                            nearestV3Distance = currentV3Distance;
                        }
                    }
                    result1[x, y] = nearestV3;
                }
            sw1.Stop();
            return sw1;
        }

        private static bool CheckResults(Vector3[,] lhs, Vector3[,] rhs)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < textureSize; x++)
                for(int y = 0; y < textureSize; y++)
                    if(!lhs[x, y].Equals(rhs[x, y]))
                        return false;
            return true;
        }

        private static void Computation(Vector3[] pointCloud, Vector3[,] result, int x, int y)
        {
            var targetPos = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
            var nearestV3 = pointCloud[0];
            Vector3 temp1 = nearestV3 - targetPos;
            var nearestV3Distance = temp1.x * temp1.x + temp1.y * temp1.y + temp1.z * temp1.z;

            for(int i = 1; i < numPoints; i++)
            {
                var currentV3 = pointCloud[i];
                Vector3 temp2 = currentV3 - targetPos;
                var currentV3Distance = temp2.x * temp2.x + temp2.y * temp2.y + temp2.z * temp2.z;
                if(currentV3Distance < nearestV3Distance)
                {
                    nearestV3 = currentV3;
                    nearestV3Distance = currentV3Distance;
                }
            }
            result[x, y] = nearestV3;
        }

        private static float DistanceToPoint(Vector3 vector, Vector3 point)
        {
            Vector3 final = vector - point;

            return final.x * final.x + final.y * final.y + final.z * final.z;
        }

        struct Vector3
        {
            public float x;
            public float y;
            public float z;

            public Vector3(float x, float y, float z)
            {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.z = z;
            }
            public Vector3(float randomDistance)
            {
                this.x = (float)rnd.NextDouble() * randomDistance;
                this.y = (float)rnd.NextDouble() * randomDistance;
                this.z = (float)rnd.NextDouble() * randomDistance;
            }

            public static Vector3 operator -(Vector3 a, Vector3 b)
            {
                return new Vector3(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y, a.z - b.z);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did some tests:  The first *improved* version brings the inlined version to parity with non-inlined, but other than that is slower than my original code (for whatever reason).  The second version (operations inlined) is vastly faster - 4s, 4s & 1.8s with x86... but 19s, 19s and 5.5 with x64.

Comment: It's late here and I actually realized I forgot to online the Vector3 subtraction operator logic. There's a good chance that'll bump perf too. Did you happen to catch that and try to inline it too? I'm off to bed for now.

Comment: Thanks, and off to bed with ya :P  I added the lastest code build [I inlined the minus for ya] in the Question.  Sadly... it's still rubbish on x64 and is really quite a poor showing from compilers if we have to go to these kinds of lengths to get decent performance!

Answer (score 3):

The struct is still 12 bytes on 64-bit system.

64-bit is slower due to no inlining for DistanceToPoint

```
 2     0 [  0] TextureFromPoints.Program+Vector3.DistanceToPoint(Vector3)
23     0 [  0] Texture!TextureFromPoints.Program+Vector3.DistanceToPoint(Vector3)
22     0 [  1]   Texture!TextureFromPoints.Program+Vector3.op_Subtraction(Vector3, Vector3)
30    22 [  0] Texture!TextureFromPoints.Program+Vector3.DistanceToPoint(Vector3)
10     0 [  1]   Texture!TextureFromPoints.Program+Vector3.sqrMagnitude()
33    32 [  0] Texture!TextureFromPoints.Program+Vector3.DistanceToPoint(Vector3)
```

On 32-bit system, only sqrtMagnitude is a function call, DistanceToPoint and op_Subtraction are inlined.

Comment: He's right. If you revise the code slighty to not use that helper method you get the same perf out of x64. I'll revise my answer with more details.

Answer (score 1):

<s>I suspect that the 64-bit performance has to do with alignment.  Your Vector3 is a 12-byte structure; these will take up 12 bytes in a 32-bit environment but they'll be padded out to 16 bytes in a 64-bit environment.  If that means your arrays are 33% larger, you can expect 33% more cache misses.</s>

My suspicion was entirely incorrect.  After sleeping on it, I tried the following:

```
class Program
{
    private struct V3
    {
        public float x;
        public float y;
        public float z;
    }

    private static unsafe long GetDistance()
    {
        var array = new V3[2];
        fixed (V3* pointerOne = &array[0])
        fixed (V3* pointerTwo = &array[1])
            return ((byte*)pointerTwo - (byte*)pointerOne);
    }

    unsafe static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetDistance());
        Console.WriteLine(sizeof(IntPtr));
    }
}
```

output, 32-bit system:

```
12
4
```

output, 64-bit system:

```
12
8
```

Comment: I like your thinking, how would I verify this theory?

Comment: Ah, yes, good point. Profiling is the way you're going to be able to see this.

Comment: That's not how alignment works. The `struct` contains 4-byte `float`s, which means each `float` has to be aligned to 4 bytes. But in this case, that doesn't change the size of the `struct` at all. And 64-bit doesn't affect alignment at all, at least if the `struct` doesn't contain any references.

Comment: @svick thanks for the correction. I was very tired when I wrote that, and as I was falling asleep, the more I thought about it, the more I thought it couldn't be right.

Comment: @NPSF3000 you wouldn't, because it's wrong.  I added some verification code to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know what to do!  Write it in F#!

```
Completed 1024x1024 pixels with 700 points in...
Sync: 4393ms
Parallel: 2409ms
```

It's faster, and smaller... not bad for something I wiped up in a few hours with little to no prior knowledge of the language.

```
module Program

open System
open System.IO
open System.Linq
open System.Threading.Tasks


let main() = 
    let numPoints = 700
    let textureSize = 1024
    let rnd = new Random()

    let randomPos() = (single (rnd.NextDouble()*(double textureSize)))
    let pointCloud = Array.init numPoints (fun _ -> (randomPos(), randomPos()))

    let distanceToPoint(sourceX :int ,sourceY : int, point ) = 
        let x = (single sourceX) - fst point
        let y = (single sourceY) - snd point
        x*x + y*y

    let syncCalc() =
        let resultData = Array2D.zeroCreate<single*single>  textureSize textureSize
        for x in 0..(textureSize-1) do
          for y in 0..(textureSize-1) do
             let mutable closestPoint = pointCloud.[0]
             let mutable closestDistance = distanceToPoint(x,y, closestPoint)
             for p in 1..(numPoints-1) do
                 let point = pointCloud.[p]
                 let distance = distanceToPoint(x,y, closestPoint)
                 if (distance < closestDistance) then
                    closestPoint <- point
                    closestDistance <- distance
             resultData.[x,y] <- closestPoint

    (*let asyncCalc() =
        let resultData = Array2D.zeroCreate<single*single>  textureSize textureSize
        let z = 
            Async.Parallel [ 
                for x in 0..(textureSize-1) -> async { 
                     for y in 0..(textureSize-1) do
                         let closestPoint = ref pointCloud.[0]
                         let closestDistance = ref (distanceToPoint(x,y, !closestPoint))
                         for p in 1..(numPoints-1) do
                             let point = pointCloud.[p]
                             let distance = distanceToPoint(x,y, !closestPoint)
                             if (distance < !closestDistance) then
                                closestPoint := point
                                closestDistance := distance
                         resultData.[x,y] <- !closestPoint
            } ]   |>Async.RunSynchronously 
        resultData*)

    let parallelCalc() =
        let resultData = Array2D.zeroCreate<single*single>  textureSize textureSize
        let z = 
            Parallel.For (0, textureSize,  fun x ->
                     for y in 0..(textureSize-1) do
                         let closestPoint = ref pointCloud.[0]
                         let closestDistance = ref (distanceToPoint(x,y, !closestPoint))
                         for p in 1..(numPoints-1) do
                             let point = pointCloud.[p]
                             let distance = distanceToPoint(x,y, !closestPoint)
                             if (distance < !closestDistance) then
                                closestPoint := point
                                closestDistance := distance
                         resultData.[x,y] <- !closestPoint)
        resultData

    //4.2s
    let sw1 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    let r1 = syncCalc() 
    sw1.Stop()

    //Slow!
    //let sw2 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    //let r2 = asyncCalc()      
    //sw2.Stop()

    //2.25s
    let sw3 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    let r3 = parallelCalc() 
    sw3.Stop()

    Console.WriteLine("Completed {0}x{0} pixels with {1} points in...", textureSize, numPoints)
    Console.WriteLine("Sync: {0}ms", sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds)
    //Console.WriteLine("ASync: {0}ms", sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds)
    Console.WriteLine("Parallel: {0}ms", sw3.ElapsedMilliseconds)
    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore

while true do main()
```